# Treeview Control Set From Treeview Object Variable?

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, treeview, ms-access-2003

I am trying to setup a Treeview Object, Set the nodes, and then update a control to have the values appropriately formatted. Right now I have the following code that works when I have it setting a control, but not a control from a variable. How do I set a local control from a variable?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim iml As ImageList
Dim TreeView0 As TreeView
Set TreeView0 = New TreeView
Set iml = New ImageList

iml.ListImages.Add , "Open", LoadPicture("Folder\Open.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "Closed", LoadPicture("Folder\Close.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "Document", LoadPicture("Folder\Document.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "test", LoadPicture("Folder\Document.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "test2", LoadPicture("Folder\Document.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "test3", LoadPicture("Folder\Document.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "test4", LoadPicture("Folder\Document.bmp")
iml.ListImages.Add , "test5", LoadPicture("Folder\Document.bmp")

Set TreeView0.ImageList = iml

TreeView0.Nodes.Add , , "Open"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add , , "Closed"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add "Open", tvwChild, "Document"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add "Open", tvwChild, "test"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add "Open", tvwChild, "test2"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add "Closed", tvwChild, "test3"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add "Closed", tvwChild, "test4"
TreeView0.Nodes.Add "Closed", tvwChild, "test5"


TreeView0.Nodes(1).Image = "Closed"
TreeView0.Nodes(1).Text = "Closed [+]"

TreeView0.Nodes(2).Image = "Closed"
TreeView0.Nodes(2).Text = "Closed [+]"

TreeView0.Nodes(3).Image = "Document"
TreeView0.Nodes(3).Text = "Document"

TreeView0.Nodes(4).Image = "test"
TreeView0.Nodes(4).Text = "test"

TreeView0.Nodes(5).Image = "test2"
TreeView0.Nodes(5).Text = "test2"

TreeView0.Nodes(6).Image = "test3"
TreeView0.Nodes(6).Text = "test3"

TreeView0.Nodes(7).Image = "test4"
TreeView0.Nodes(7).Text = "test4"

TreeView0.Nodes(8).Image = "test5"
TreeView0.Nodes(8).Text = "test5"

'THIS LINE FAILS (Property Invalid)
TreeViewTest = TreeView0

End Sub

Private Sub TreeView0_DblClick() 'OK


If TreeView0.Nodes(1).Expanded = True Then
    TreeView0.Nodes(1).Image = "Open"
    TreeView0.Nodes(1).Text = "Open [-]"
ElseIf TreeView0.Nodes(1).Expanded = False Then
    TreeView0.Nodes(1).Image = "Closed"
    TreeView0.Nodes(1).Text = "Closed [+]"
End If


If TreeView0.Nodes(2).Expanded = True Then
    TreeView0.Nodes(2).Image = "Open"
    TreeView0.Nodes(2).Text = "Open [-]"
ElseIf TreeView0.Nodes(2).Expanded = False Then
    TreeView0.Nodes(2).Image = "Closed"
    TreeView0.Nodes(2).Text = "Closed [+]"
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried 'Set' keyword for object varaible:  set TreeViewTest = TreeView0

Comment: and why you need to 'set a local control from a variable' instead of setup control itself?

Comment: Yes. It throws an invalid use of property.

Why not see if you can instead of setting up the control? More tools on one's belt is never a bad thing.

Comment: please try this  'Set Me.TreeViewTest.Object = TreeView0'

Comment: Using `Set Me.TreeView0.Object = TreeViewTest` returns the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Is this a VB6 Form/Control, or an MS Access form?

Comment: It is an Access - 2003 Form, VB6 Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set a form control from a variable.  What you can do is declare a variable, then set the form control to that variable and modify that variable's properties.  With MSForms (presumably Access forms?) you can also declare form variables and then add them to forms at runtime.

So I see two problems with your code.  The first is that since the TreeControl is an ActiveX variable, you need to declare the `TreeView0` variable as a `CustomControl` not a `TreeView`.  Then you need to set the form control to the variable.   ie `Set TreeView0 = Me.TreeViewTest`.

So the code would be:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim iml As ImageList
    Dim TreeView0 As CustomControl
    'Set TreeView0 = New TreeView -> not needed as you set the control to the variable
    Set iml = New ImageList

    Set TreeView0 = Me.TreeViewTest

    'Do the rest of you initialisation here.
End Sub
```

If you want to reuse this code (why else would you want to set it from a variable?) then you simply change this to:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    InitMyTree(Me.TreeViewTest)
    InitMyTree(Me.TreeViewTest1)
End Sub
```

And then sinmply the following function (note you don't need to declare the variable within the function).

```
Private Sub InitMyTree(TreeView0 as CustomControl)
    Dim iml As ImageList:    Set iml = New ImageList

    iml.ListImages.Add , "Open", LoadPicture("Folder\Open.bmp")
    iml.ListImages.Add , "Closed", LoadPicture("Folder\Close.bmp")

    'Finish initialisation here.
End Sub
```